# Custom CKEditor 5 has no toolbar at all in angular 8 application

Tags: angular, angular8, ckeditor5

I have installed ckeditor and its classic build as below:

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

Since I wanted to add a lot of plugins, I used ckeditor's [online builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/) to create a custom build. I copied only the 'build' folder into my angular application's src folder.

Did a usual

```
npm install
```

Imported the module in my module as below:

```
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  CKEditorModule,
  FormsModule
],
```

and in my component

```
import * as Editor from '../ck-build/build/ckeditor';

public Editor = Editor;
```

and in the html page its a simple form

```
  <form>
    <ckeditor name="title" [(ngModel)]="title" [editor]="Editor"></ckeditor>
  </form>
```

Now, when I run the application, I get the editor without a toolbar. I get the editor along with the model data but not the toolbar.

Could someone help with what could I be doing wrong here?

PS - There are no errors in the console

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
Its solved when the editor has [config] attriubte with toolbar items. And the editor need to bootstrap as DecoupledEditor (just like the example) => https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html